# How to save Audiocontext each audio track into database?

Tags: web-audio-api

I have a Audiocontext object in which audio's are given dynamically through xmlhttprequest and JS Filereader , is there is any possibility to save the mixed audio as an mp3 ?

Comment: The question is not clear to me, but you could have a look at [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext).

Comment: To get the audiocontext track and save in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution by @john_white 's comment over the question

```
var OAC         = new OfflineAudioContext(2,44100*length,44100);

        AudioApp.Collections.Tracks.each(function(track) {
                track.clips.each(function(clip) {
                        var newBufferSource         = OAC.createBufferSource();
                        newBufferSource.buffer      = clip.get('buffer');
                        newBufferSource.connect(OAC.destination);
                        newBufferSource.start(OAC.currentTime + clip.get('trackPos'));
                });
        });
```